# Any known health hazards due to rusty metal on the inside of a microwave oven?

Tags: food-safety, metal, microwaves, healthy-cooking

Imagine a metal microwave which is a bit rusty, also on the inside. Would there be any health hazards due to the condition of this metal, when using the microwave oven?